# Which option will firm chose to minimize costs?

Tags: economics

As head of the planning commission of Eastern Motors, your job is to determine where to locate a new plant. The only inputs used in your cars are steel and labor and the production function is Cobb-Douglas where $$f(S,L) = S^{0.5} L^{0.5}$$  where $S$ is tons of steel and $L$ is units of labor.

You can locate your plant either in country A or country B. In country A, steel costs 7\$  and labor costs 7\$. In country B, steel costs \$8 and labor costs 6\$. In which country should the company locate its new plant so as to minimize costs per unit of output,  minimize the cost of production?

F(L,S) = L^.5 S^.5
MRTS= MP (S)/ MP(L)=Price of steel/price of labour

COUNTRY A
L/S=1
L=S
TCost =7L+7S

Country B
l/s=8/6
L=4S/3

T cost = 8S+6L

i dont know what to do next?

Comment: Are you looking to minimize the production costs or maximize the production output? Not sure what *production function* means in this context...

Comment: Minimize the cost of production, as in minimize the cost per unit of output, asmentioned in the question

Comment: So would you not compute the minimization functions and conditions in each country and minimize? Can you update teh question with minimization function and conditions you get for every country?

Comment: _Welcome to Math.SE!_ In general, please provide more context to your question (in particular where it comes from - class exercise, book exercise, ...?) and take care of grammar and formatting. Proper formatting will make is easier to read and understand your question.